# Ejb jax-rpc web services with basic authentication how to get username and password of a request

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, jboss, ejb-3.0

The problem is clear as I mentioned in the title, any help would be appreciated...

By the way, my services are running on Jboss 4.2.2GA and I am using MyEclipse7.5
Moreover, here what I have tried before but did not work for me;

```
@Stateless
@WebService(name = "BaseService", targetNamespace = "http://base.ws.listingapi.gg.com")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@WebContext(contextRoot = "/listingapi/ws")
public abstract class BaseService {
    ..

    MessageContext mctx = webServiceContext.getMessageContext();

    webServiceContext.getUserPrincipal(); //WITH THIS ONE I could get the username but of course not password..
    System.out.println(mctx.get("password"));

    Map http_headers = (Map) mctx.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
    List userList = (List) http_headers.get("Username");
    List passList = (List) http_headers.get("Password");
```

**[SOLVED]**
I have found the solution, here it is;

```
@Context
protected HttpServletRequest request;
```

Or

```
@Context
protected WebServiceContext context;
```

...

```
    request.getUserPrincipal().getName(); 
    //OR
    context.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    //will return the username used to getting logged in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] I have found the solution, here it is;

```
@Context
protected HttpServletRequest request;
```

Or

```
@Context
protected WebServiceContext context;
```

...

```
request.getUserPrincipal().getName(); 
//OR
context.getUserPrincipal().getName();
//will return the username used to getting logged in
```